# How can I create a type that uses fluent chaining syntax without requiring parenthesis?

Tags: rust, fluent, assertion

I'm trying to make an assertions library for testing in Rust. Currently, I have statements like:

```
expect(value).to().be().equal_to(4);
```

It would be really nice to drop the parens on filler `to` and `be` functions to make it something like:

```
expect(value).to.be.equal_to(4);
```

I think this requires the `to` and `be` to be fields on struct returned by `expect` (`Expectation`). It currently looks like this:

```
struct Expectation<V: Debug> {
    value: V,
}
```

Is it possible to make it something like this:

```
struct Expectation<V: Debug> {
    value: V,
    to: Box<Expectation<V>>,
    be: Box<Expectation<V>>,
}
```

where `to` and `be` point to the struct they're in?

I've tried, but it's a tricky one to construct. I'm not even sure it is safe if the object is moved (maybe that can be prevented via `Pin`?).

I'm looking for any solution to allow the `expect(value).to.be` syntax above.

Comment: I'm kind of astonished that version with the filler is seen as more ergonomic or friendly than `expect(value).equal_to(4)` or even `expect_equal(value, 4)`

Comment: That's just one (hasty, small) example - not really here to debate the ergonomics of it (although I will say it does make a difference for larger assertions, especially with many composed together - see hamcrest or assertj for similar in Java). Also makes a nice brain teaser/is helping me learn rust.

Comment: I like the syntax, but *only in languages where it's normal*. Write code that goes with the aesthetic of the ecosystem, not just what you've used before. More pithily, **when in Rome, do as the Romans do**.

Comment: See also: [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423)

Answer (score 4):

> I'm looking for any solution to allow the `expect(value).to.be` syntax above.

Keep it simple then:

```
fn main() {
    expect(4).to.be.equal_to(3);
}

fn expect<T>(actual: T) -> To<T> {
    let be = Be {
        be: Expectation(actual),
    };
    To { to: be }
}

struct To<T> {
    pub to: Be<T>,
}

struct Be<T> {
    pub be: Expectation<T>,
}

struct Expectation<T>(T);

impl<T> Expectation<T> {
    fn equal_to<U>(&self, expected: U)
    where
        U: PartialEq<T>,
    {
        if expected != self.0 {
            panic!("Report error")
        }
    }
}
```

> optionally want to skip [`to` and `be`]

```
use std::{ops::Deref, rc::Rc};

fn main() {
    expect(4).to.be.equal_to(3);
    expect(4).to.equal_to(3);
    expect(4).equal_to(3);
}

fn expect<T>(actual: T) -> Expectation<T> {
    let core = Core(Rc::new(actual));

    let be = Be { core: core.clone() };

    let to = To {
        be,
        core: core.clone(),
    };

    Expectation {
        to,
        core: core.clone(),
    }
}

struct Expectation<T> {
    pub to: To<T>,
    core: Core<T>,
}

impl<T> Deref for Expectation<T> {
    type Target = Core<T>;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Core<T> {
        &self.core
    }
}

struct To<T> {
    pub be: Be<T>,
    core: Core<T>,
}

impl<T> Deref for To<T> {
    type Target = Core<T>;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Core<T> {
        &self.core
    }
}

struct Be<T> {
    core: Core<T>,
}

impl<T> Deref for Be<T> {
    type Target = Core<T>;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Core<T> {
        &self.core
    }
}

struct Core<T>(Rc<T>);

impl<T> Clone for Core<T> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        Core(self.0.clone())
    }
}

impl<T> Core<T> {
    fn equal_to<U>(&self, expected: U)
    where
        U: PartialEq<T>,
    {
        if expected != *self.0 {
            panic!("Report error")
        }
    }
}
```

Some macros would reduce duplication, but I was too lazy to actually show that ;-)

## When in Rome...

I would try to play to Rust's strengths when designing a test assertions library. To me, this means using traits to allow people to easily add custom assertions.

```
use crate::testlib::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    expect(4).to(be.equal_to(3));
    expect(4).to(equal_to(3));
}

mod testlib {
    // Shorthand variants that will always be imported.
    // Minimize what's in here to avoid name collisions
    pub mod prelude {
        use super::*;

        pub fn expect<A>(actual: A) -> Expectation<A> {
            Expectation::new(actual)
        }

        #[allow(non_upper_case_globals)]
        pub static be: Be = Be;

        pub fn equal_to<E>(expected: E) -> EqualTo<E> {
            EqualTo::new(expected)
        }

    }

    // All the meat of the implementation. Can be divided up nicely.

    pub trait Assertion<A> {
        fn assert(&self, actual: &A);
    }

    pub struct Expectation<A>(A);
    impl<A> Expectation<A> {
        pub fn new(actual: A) -> Self {
            Expectation(actual)
        }

        pub fn to(&self, a: impl Assertion<A>) {
            a.assert(&self.0)
        }
    }

    pub struct Be;

    impl Be {
        pub fn equal_to<E>(&self, expected: E) -> EqualTo<E> {
            EqualTo::new(expected)
        }
    }

    pub struct EqualTo<E>(E);

    impl<E> EqualTo<E> {
        pub fn new(expected: E) -> Self {
            EqualTo(expected)
        }
    }

    impl<A, E> Assertion<A> for EqualTo<E>
    where
        A: PartialEq<E>,
    {
        fn assert(&self, actual: &A) {
            if *actual != self.0 {
                panic!("report an error")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Next steps I'd look into:

- An assertion should probably report failures to some passed-in struct, not panic.
- Add a `to_not` and/or `not_to` negative matcher.
- Add composition of assertions.

Comment: Ah, this works nicely for the case where you always have to use `to` and `be` but not even you optionally want to skip them out. (which I realise I didn't state as a requirement above). Nice idea though!

Answer (score 2):

I've had some success with lazily generating the `to` and `be` using the [`thunk`](https://github.com/sdleffler/thunk-rs) crate:

```
struct Expectation<V: Debug> {
    value: Rc<V>,
    to: Thunk<Box<Expectation<V>>>,
    be: Thunk<Box<Expectation<V>>>,
}

fn expect<V: Debug>(value: V) -> Expectation<V> {
    expect_rc(Rc::new(value))
}

fn expect_rc<V: Debug>(value: Rc<V>) -> Expectation<V> {
    let to_cloned = value.clone();
    let be_cloned = value.clone();
    Expectation {
        value,
        to: Thunk::defer(|| Box::new(expect_rc(to_cloned))),
        be: Thunk::defer(|| Box::new(expect_rc(be_cloned))),
    }
}

impl<V: PartialEq + Debug> Expectation<V> {
    fn equals<R: Debug>(&self, expected: R)
    where
        V: PartialEq<R> + Clone,
    {
        assert_eq!(self.value.deref().clone(), expected);
    }
}
```

This works as I'd expect, thanks to magic of [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) + [`Deref` conversion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#more-on-deref-coercion):

```
expect(4).to.be.equal_to(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

For designing a custom syntax, I'd just use a macro:

```rust
macro_rules! expect {
    ($subject:expr, to, $($attr:tt)*) => {
        expect!($subject, $($attr)*)
    };
    ($subject:expr, be, $($attr:tt)*) => {
        expect!($subject, $($attr)*)
    };
    ($subject:expr, equal_to $object:expr) => {
        assert_eq!($subject, $object)
    };
}

expect!(1, to, be, equal_to 1);
```

Deploying boxes and self-referential structs just to get a particular syntax is overkill.

[Link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d95520951b91009a4d4c064eefedccdd)

Comment: Yeah, with macros you can do anything. I'm actually trying to avoid macros in this library as it's main raison d'etre in order to get good IDE autocompletion/support and better extensibility and composability.